# Automatically stacking excel sheet data on top of each other in a new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Is there a formula (can be a user defined VBA formula) that will automatically stack specified sheets on top of each other?

The formula can't involve the "Indirect" Excel Formula due to associated volatile performance issues.

Hopefully

[image: this image]

helps illustrate the idea

Answer (score 0):

The "no volatiles" rule eliminates a lot of possibilities.  If you were to allow INDIRECT, then there are a number of ways to create this via formula without VBA.  Even with VBA, I suspect that you would have to make the function volatile to work each time there is a change in the Sheets 1, 2, ..., but I am not sure of all of your requirements.

There is a way to do this via Power Query as well and it could avoid volatiles, but you would have to save the file and then refresh the table each time you want to update Stacked Sheets.  Allowing the use of OFFSET would allow you to use Power Query with Refresh while avoiding having to save your file and then Refresh.

Method: in each worksheet that contains data to be stacked, create a Named Range with a scope limited to that worksheet.

[image]

The formula would look like this for each:

```
=OFFSET( $A$1, 0, 0, COUNTA($A:$A), 2 )
```

Now where you have "Sheets I want stacked (inputs)" in B2, create a table by typing clicking in that list and holding CTRL-T. Tell it your table has headers. I made mine in cell A1 like this:

[image]

This is a dynamic table that will resize itself as you add or remove sheet names.  In the Table Design tab, you can rename this from Table1 to something more logical.  I named mine tS2Stack.

[image]

Now click anywhere inside of the table, go to the Data tab and click From Table/Range

[image]

This will open Power Query.  In Power Query editor, click on New Source and choose Blank Query.

[image]

It will have a default of Query1, but you can rename it what you like. I named it factStack.  Then past over the existing script with this script.

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Name], "_Drange")),
  #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Text Before Delimiter", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Name], "!"), type text),
  #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter", {"Text Before Delimiter"}, tS2Stack, {"Sheets to Stack"}, "tS2Stack", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded tS2Stack" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "tS2Stack", {"Sheets to Stack"}, {"tS2Stack.Sheets to Stack"}),
  #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded tS2Stack", each ([tS2Stack.Sheets to Stack] <> null)),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Content"}),
  #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Content", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Content.Column1", "Content.Column2"})
in
    #"Expanded Content"
```

Choose Close and Load from the Home tab of Power Query.  You can load the table where you want.  I put mine side by side with the tS2Stack table.  Whenever you want to update it right click and Refresh it.

[image]

Comment: Since `OFFSET` is also volatile, I suggest the non-volatile `=$A$1:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($A:$A),1)`

Comment: What a great idea. I could not think of a way to make a dynamic range without OFFSET.  I will use your method in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Columns

- This is a VBA solution. You only run `StackColumns`.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub StackColumns()
    
    Const dName As String = "Stacked Sheets"
    Const drFirst As String = "A3" ' Read
    Const dwFirst As String = "B3" ' Write
    
    Const sFirst As String = "A1:B1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim wsData As Variant: wsData = GetColumns(dws.Range(drFirst))
    If IsEmpty(wsData) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = dws.Range(sFirst).Columns.Count
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = UBound(wsData, 1)
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(1 To wsCount)
    Dim rData() As Long: ReDim rData(1 To wsCount)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, drCount As Long, dwCount As Long
    For r = 1 To wsCount
        Set sws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = wb.Worksheets(wsData(r, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then
            drCount = drCount + 1
            sData(drCount) = GetColumns(sws.Range(sFirst))
            If IsEmpty(sData(drCount)) Then
                drCount = drCount - 1
            Else
                rData(drCount) = UBound(sData(drCount))
                dwCount = dwCount + rData(drCount)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If wsCount > drCount Then
        ReDim Preserve sData(1 To drCount)
        ReDim Preserve rData(1 To drCount)
    End If
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dwCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim c As Long, n As Long, d As Long
    
    For r = 1 To drCount
        For n = 1 To rData(r)
            d = d + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(d, c) = sData(r)(n, c)
            Next c
        Next n
    Next r
    
    With dws.Range(dwFirst).Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(dwCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - dwCount + 1) _
            .Offset(dwCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub

Function GetColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Variant
    
    If FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount + cCount = 2 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    GetColumns = Data

End Function
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Stacked Sheets`**

- To further automate this, you have to add the following procedure to the sheet module where you want this to run, i.e. the sheet module of the `Stacked Sheets` worksheet. Then, only when you change a value in the range with the worksheet names manually or via VBA code (not via formula), `StackColumns` will run automatically.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const drFirst As String = "A3"
    Dim rg As Range
    With Me.Range(drFirst)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    If Not Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then
        StackColumns
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reference a cell from another sheet with `=SheetName!A1`, then if you copy and paste that formula to the next row it would automatically translate to `=SheetName!B1` and so forth. There may be a more elegant way to pull a range or use VBA but in the time I spent tinkering with this that's what I was able to get working. May be helpful as a slightly more manual approach until you can find something better.